# Select Xml Node using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, lambda, linq-to-xml

my Xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCustomer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Customer>
        <CustomerId>1f323c97-2015-4a3d-9956-a93115c272ea</CustomerId>
        <FirstName>Aria</FirstName>
        <LastName>Stark</LastName>
        <DOB>1999-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerId>c9c326c2-1e27-440b-9b25-c79b1d9c80ed</CustomerId>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Snow</LastName>
        <DOB>1983-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
    </Customer>
</ArrayOfCustomer>
```

my attempt :

```
XElement toEdit = 
    (XElement)doc.Descendants("ArrayOfCustomer")
                 .Descendants("Customer")
                 .Where(x => Guid.Parse((x.Descendants("CustomerId") as XElement).Value) == customer.CustomerId)
                 .First<XElement>();
```

this throws the following exception :

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

1) isn't `x` an `XElement`?

2) is this a proper where lambda for selecting an Xml node?

3) and of course how would you find this node according to `CustomerId`?

Comment: i first got the exception :
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.
this was because i tried to cast from IEnumrable to a single XElement  , i added a First<XElement>() extension to it .
now it just can't make out x as an XElement .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `Descendents` and `Where` return an `IEnumerable<XElement>` not a single `XElement` which is what you're after.  You can fix this like this:

```
XElement toEdit = doc.Descendants("ArrayOfCustomer")
                     .Descendants("Customer")
                     .Where(x => Guid.Parse(x.Descendants("CustomerId").Single().Value) == customer.CustomerId)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Just be aware this requires there be only one CustomerId element beneath a Customer. If there is 0 or > 1 it will throw an exception. And after looking at his XML it is probably appropriate. But just something to point out.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell while were on the subject , how would you go about editing that node , i can now update all of Customer's (XElement) decedents 
but how would update the node in the file?

Answer (score 2):

You are not casting `x` you are casting `x.Descendants()`. x.Descendants() returns a collection, hence the plural method semantic.  Off the top of my head you should be able to do `x.Descendants("CustomerId").FirstOrDefault() as XElement`

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement toEdit = (from c in doc.Descendants("Customer")
     where Guid.Parse(c.Value) == customer.CustomerId
     select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure your query like this:

```
 XElement toEdit = doc.Descendants("Customer")
                      .Where(x => (Guid)x.Element("CustomerId") == customer.CustomerId)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```