# how to do find/count on xmlnodelist in c# - is xmlnodelist.childnodes.asqueryable() a good way?

Tags: c#, xml, nodes, xmlnodelist, asqueryable

i have a legit XmlNodeList lets call it nodelist
i can call nodelist.ChildNodes and that works 
i can also call nodelist.ChildNodes.AsQueryable()
but then when i try nodelist.ChildNodes.AsQueryable().Where(x=>x....)  that fails

i have included

```
using System.Linq
```

but im kinda at a loss how to 
1. find specific nodes
2. count the nodes that start with a specific key ie

```
<key1 attrib1="xxx">yyy</key1>
```

how many nodes are there with key="key1"

pls note: before i get yelled at for duplicate posting - 
i have spent HOURS over a coupla days trying to figure out how to do this 
and nothing on stack has been clear enough (for me anyways...)

thx - you guys are great

UPDATE:  ok so whats interesting is that 
even tho i got downgraded - nobody (immediately that is) had a solution to my exact question
which is how to do this with xmlnodelist
what people did have were alternate answers - all good
so it doesnt seem that xmlnodelist asqueryable does what the name implies

1) using xmlnode.selectnodes() 
which a very good example can be found here
[Select Xml Node using Linq to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082883/select-xml-node-using-linq-to-xml)

2) XML class (see selected answer)

Comment: Your questions in the post are not related to title (partially because you don't need to use `AsQueryable` at all to find/count nodes)... Possibly some XML/XPath tutorial is what you need. But if you really looking for `AsQueryable` to be useful you should cast `ChildNodes` to strongly typed enumerable first: `nodelist.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().AsQueryable()`

Comment: thx @AlexeiLevenkov - yes i could easily be barking up the wrong tree.  if there are better ways to do a find/count pls post and i will adjust title.  thx!

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do.  You should make a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), which has **relevant** code that you already have, a clear description about what's failing, and also include exactly what output you want.

Comment: Thanks for title edit. Make sure to remove thank you notes/searched alot from the post as not related. Please check out this search results http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+xml+select+nodes to see if you can clarify what information you could not find. Also show sample of different  "nodes that start with a specific key" - node in XML have name, namespace, and attributes - but no "key".

Comment: thx @AlexeiLevenkov - ok so just fyi - i understand that you want the thx/search alot stuff out - but clearly it needed to be stated since ive already been downgraded.  also i like to show apprec for peoples knowledge and willingness to help - theres too little of that in the world.   and sam - i didnt post an SSCCE originally cause it wasnt necessary within the scope of the orig title.  thx alexei for the direction.  will go check it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt to put your XML into a custom class and query the custom class. It's more work, but man is the pay off worth it. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784895/populate-custom-list-sub-class-from-xml-document-via-linq) question for info on how to do it.

Comment: thx @volearix!  never thought of this concept but its fascinating

Comment: No problem, it came up as a requirement in a project I was working on recently and really made things much, MUCH easier in the end.